# Mail Merge in Word - Auto add additional rows in a table

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I am using mail merge in word to create letters to send to banks about upcoming transactions. Each bank will have several transactions per letter that vary daily. I set it up but it’s only pulling in 1 row from the linked Excel sheet and not the rest. Is there a way I can set it up so if it sees the bank name listed multiple times in the Excel sheet it will add all the transactions on one letter by creating a new row for each transaction?

This will make this currently extremely manual process much easier and mitigate risk.

Can anyone help please?

I tried an IFTHEN formula but it didn’t quite work. I’m thinking I need some code that includes something along the lines of “IF = Bank Name = Bank Name,THEN (code for auto add new row), add next transaction. I just don’t know what that code would look like.

Comment: As it stands, this is out of scope for StackOverflow, which is really for questions/answers on specific programming problems. You'd probably be better off posting in SuperIser (there's an answer to a related question at https://superuser.com/questions/1580590/how-to-use-two-access-data-sources-in-word-mailmerge , for example, and/or A Google search for "Microsoft Word Many to one Mailmerge" should lead to  most of the techniques used to solve this problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html